# how to read problems explorer view in eclipse programatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

is there any way to read the eclipse problem view programatically in eclipse plugin.

I want to fetch data from the following screen-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: Ask the workbench for all `Marker`s of type `IMarker.PROBLEM`. The documentation contains a [code snippet for this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm):

```
   IMarker[] problems = null;
   int depth = IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE;
   try {
      problems = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, depth);
   } catch (CoreException e) {
      // something went wrong
   }
```

To get the workspace root, use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();`

The file `MarkerTypesModel.java` contains this code:

```
private String getWellKnownLabel(String type) {
    if (type.equals(IMarker.PROBLEM)) {
        return "Problem";//$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    if (type.equals(IMarker.TASK)) {
        return "Task";//$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    if (type.equals("org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
        return "Java Problem";//$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return type;
}
```

As you can see, it compares the type with a fixed string to produce `Java Problem` (and the NON_NLS-Comments are wrong, too).

Comment: everything worked but I am unable to find the details of column TYpe , but I am getting some the marker id on calling marker.getType() , any suggestion to get the string value like Java Problem

Comment: I think `type` will always be `IMarker.PROBLEM`. Look into the map behind `getAttribute()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but what I found is there are more types of problems exist like Eclipseplugin xml problem , if using CDT different VHDF problem , for .sql files , its query problem, so as of now I am just reading the file extension and upating that problem , but concern is if eclipse is updating its Table model , then where is that api ..

Comment: It's in `org.eclipse.ui.ide`.